# Exception with 64Bit Unit Test in Visual Studio 2008 Professional

Tags: c#, 32bit-64bit, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am trying to Unit-Test a 64 Bit C++/CLI-Project and therefore have a Unit-Test-Project. With 32-Bit Settings everything works fine, but when switching to 64 Bit I get an exception:

```
Class Initialization method MyTestProject.MyTest.MyClassInitialize threw exception. System.BadImageFormatException:
```

Tried setting the test project to **Any CPU** and **x64**, same result. Found this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531%28v=vs.100%29.aspx where it is described to set the unit test running as 64 bit process.

I don't see this settings and think this is because I don't have the Ultimate Version. I only have Professional.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Joerg

---

Edit:
Sorry, was working with VS2008 and therefore this question was stupid. Please see link in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think because you use a dll how don't support 64bit.
you have to check used dlls

Comment: Do you mean the UnitTest-dll or the dll that I want to test? I think the problem is in the UnitTest-dll (see exception).

Comment: @joerg is your ClassInitialize Methode populated ? if yes you can make the code

Comment: The `MyClassInitialize`-Function is a public function in the UnitTest, this was generated by default. What do you mean with "populated" and "make the code"?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry for confusion! This was my error: I generally work with VS2010 but this project is in VS2008. And I just found out that 64Bit unit tests are not possible there. See this link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/keithmg/archive/2009/04/02/x64-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2008-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-unittestframework-dll.aspx